# Action icon looks like disabled on all tabs, but the extension works

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am concerned because [this is the only icon that looks like an extension off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOcf0.png)

Please, somebody edit the code so that the icon looked enabled on each tab, as well as the other icons extensions.

Files of the extension u can [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnugrr7n9zaoole/ScrollBar%20Anywhere.zip?dl=0) or find "Scrollbar Anywhere" in chrome appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome recently (around v.48) switched to a unified extension toolbar where all extensions are displayed so that nonsavvy users would see all that useless cruft they installed on shady web sites. That's the reason behind this change.

A gray icon in the toolbar doesn't mean the extension doesn't work.

It just means that:

- no toolbar button declared in manifest because neither icon nor popup are needed,
- a page action is declared but current page doesn't match the declared URL pattern.

On the other hand, if you disable it on chrome://extensions page (Menu -> Settings -> Extensions)
there would be no button at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I understand that the extension at the same time work, just want to know whether it is possible to change the files so that the icon was "richer", as if enabled.

Comment: Well, you can add an icon using [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) API, but StackOverflow isn't a place for "do-it-for-me-please" requests.

Comment: Oh,lol,how could I forget about this parameter, thanks for reminding me.